# Bootstrap multiselect sends no data when all is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I use this bootstrap plugin for a mutliselect: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

My problem is this, if I select only one option no problem, the data is sent by form and I can process it, but if I select all, no data is sent.

Here is the corresponding select:

```
<form method="post" action="save_event.php" onsubmit="loadWaitScreen();" id="formevent">
    <select class="custom-select" id="eventTags" name="eventTags[]" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="1">party</option>
       <option value="2">Lounge</option
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript part:

```js
        function loadWaitScreen() {
            $.LoadingOverlay("show", {
                image: "",
                fontawesome: "fa fa-cog fa-spin"
            });
        }

        $('#eventTags').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            maxHeight: 400,
            dropUp: true,
            buttonText: function(options) {
                if (options.length === 0) {
                    return 'Nothing selected';
                } else if (options.length > 3) {
                    return options.length + ' selected';
                } else {
                    var selected = [];
                    options.each(function () {
                        selected.push([$(this).text(), $(this).data('order')]);
                    });

                    selected.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a[1] - b[1];
                    });

                    var text = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                        text += selected[i][0] + ', ';
                    }

                    return text.substr(0, text.length - 2);
                }
            },
        });
```

The PHP part:

```php
if (!User::isUserLogin()) {
    header('Location: ' . $link);
    exit();
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
....
```

The output

```
array(24) {
  ["eventName"]=>
  string(21) " asdf asdf asdf asdf "
  ["eventDesc"]=>
  string(25) "
sdf asdf asd fasdf

"
  ["eventDescShort"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["eventPlace"]=>
  string(43) "uuitzui"
  ["eventDate"]=>
  string(10) "2021-01-10"
  ["eventTime"]=>
  string(5) "13:49"
  ["eventRegisterDate"]=>
  string(10) "2021-01-08"
  ["eventRegisterDateEnd"]=>
  string(10) "2021-01-10"
  ["eventRegisterTimeEnd"]=>
  string(5) "13:49"
  ["eventWaitlistStopDate"]=>
  string(10) "2021-01-08"
  ["eventParticipants"]=>
  string(3) "150"
  ["eventParticipantsReservation"]=>
  string(2) "15"
  ["typeEvent"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["registerSeatplanDistancecount"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["distancetype"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["amount"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["seats"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["netpricePerSeat"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["taxRate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["entryQrCodePIN"]=>
  string(4) "6213"
  ["eventSeparateMailAddress"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["eventDeleteDate"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["sendPlan"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["eventOnHold"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: If there's a working snippet `[<>]` it will be far easier for us to debug. Can you please create a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

The below solution ,I found that's work in my case

Declare `var selected = [];` globally

```
var selected = [];

$('#eventTags').multiselect({
    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: '300',
    buttonWidth: '235',
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var brand = $('#eventTags option:selected');
        // var selected = []; - Declare globally
        $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
            selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried, I see my selected values in the console, but when I send the form, I see nothing, only when I select not all...

Comment: can you please add code for submit data ?

Comment: check my edited answer ,Declare `var selected = [];` globally

Comment: Still the same, see my output ahead.

Comment: add `loadWaitScreen()` this method in the question

Comment: added above, I don't think that this is the problem